# VSTS step to pull from repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, repository, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline (which pulls from our VSTS repos) but I would like to pull from another VSTS repo during the pipeline, based on environment parameters.

Is this possible? If so, which step should I use?

I know NPM can be used to pull from a repo, but I feel that using NPM to do something which VSTS can (and will already have done during the pipeline execution) is overkill.

There does not appear to be a build step with a name akin to "git pull" or "azure repo ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the Command Line task and use all `git` commands (clone/pull):

[image]

Or install an extension from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=git&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) that do the same thing, for example - [Git Repository Downloader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fakhrulhilal-maktum.GitDownloader):

[image]

Comment: Ah, there we are! Thanks :)